# JavaFX: Объединение Filechooser и DirectoryChooser

Tags: java, файлы, javafx

Мой тул заменяет текст файлов (их название и/или содержимое).Собственно для этих целей мне нужно, как иметь возможность выбирать название файла, так и папку (чтобы применять возможности рефакторинга к ее вложенным файлам). Копаясь в интернете, путного ничего не нашел. Есть две реализации, упомянутые в тайтле. Может кто сталкивался с этой проблемой и сможет помочь? Вот кусочки кода, демонстрирующие эти два диалога.

```
private void defineFilePathWithDirectoryChooser(){
    DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    chooser.setTitle("Define Root File");
    File defaultDirectory = new File("ur directory");
    chooser.setInitialDirectory(defaultDirectory);
    File selectedDirectory = chooser.showDialog(stage);
    if (selectedDirectory != null) {
        this.filePath = selectedDirectory.toString();
        filepathfld.setText(this.filePath);
    }
}


private void defineFilePathWithFileChooser() {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Define Root File");
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
    if (selectedFile != null) {
        this.filePath = selectedFile.toString();
        filepathfld.setText(this.filePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо вам придеться писать свой кастомный компонент, потому как судя по [этой ишью](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8102208) не все платформы могут поддержать одновременно выбор директории и файлов, поэтому этого не будет в `javafx`